# onclick not being added to element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code attempts to add an onclick event [to fire a function called test()] by specifying the element's id after it has been created:

```js
function pathContents(fileList)
{
 var $list = $('<ul/>');
    $.each(fileList, function (_, file) {
  $('<li/>').addClass('filechoice').prop('id', file).text(file).appendTo($list);
  $('#' + file).click(test());
    });
    return $list;
}
```

However, the debugger shows that onclick is null:
[image]

The test() function exists in the same .js file as the pathContents function.  Why isn't this working?

Comment: does `test()` return a function ? If not, then you might wanna do `.click(test)` instead, cause `click` expects you pass it a function as a handler.

Comment: test() is a separate function.

Comment: Read again @YemSalat's comment

Comment: The test() function right now does this: `console.log('reached test');`  When `.click(test)` is used, nothing happens.  When `.click(test())` is used the console prints out "reached test" (without the quotes).  What am I missing about YemSalat's post?

Comment: You are passing result of the function instead of the function itself to `click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your DOM element for that ID is created before you try to add a click event to it, otherwise it will not be created since there is no existing tag with that ID.

Comment: The line immediately before the .click appends an li to $list with an id equal to the value of whatever is in the 'file' item of the array.  Maybe this approach won't work...?

Comment: Your $list contains the new elements, but you never actually append them to the DOM and then you return it away from the function, you would need to append it before calling the click event

Comment: The `.appendTo($list)` at the very end of that long line of code won't work for adding the click event right after?

Comment: The appendTo adds it to the variable, but NOT to your actual HTML/DOM, you would need to do something like

Comment: Below should work I haven't tested it but you get the idea

`function pathContents(fileList)
{
var test = [];
 var $list = $('<ul/>');
    $.each(fileList, function (_, file) {
  $('<li/>').addClass('filechoice').prop('id', file).text(file).appendTo($list);
    test.push(file);

    });
$(target).append($list);
for(var t in test){
  $('#' + t).click(test());
}
}`

Comment: The console is showing "ReferenceError: target is not defined".  Got any ideas?

Comment: I can see that it works (yay!); however, I got lost on this line of code in the jsfiddle: `$("#test").append($list);`.  Where does #test come from?

Comment: The test is an ID that I created in the HTML to append my created list to the actual page, look up the Jquery documentation on .append() but it is actually used to get the list you created to show up on the screen, which has to be there to try to attach a click handler

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now.

Comment: Perfect! Always remember when you're adding a click event make sure there is a DOM element or the page is loaded

Comment: One more follow up question - it seems that `for(var t in test)` is giving the key of each element of the array.  How can the value be accessed?

Comment: Its not, I just put the test array as ['1','2','3'], that can be whatever you want, a for in/for each loop will only get the values for an array by default

Comment: That follow up question surfaced when trying to incorporate this code into the program.  I changed the test() function's name to test1() to avoid possible conflict with the test in the for loop (the console was complaining).  Then I did this `$('#' + test[t]).click(test1());` because 'file' contains file names (string).  I think it might be working now...more testing to do though.

Comment: t will actually contain the value, not the index, you do not need to use `test[t]` just `t`

Comment: Oh, yes - that seems to work.  When I did `alert(t);` it showed integers.  When I did `alert(test[t]);` it showed the values.  But doing `$('#' +t).click(test1());` seems to work fine as well.

Comment: Is it preferable to use one over the other?  The longer version, with `test[t]` makes more sense to my brain because it's similar to PHP (which I have a lot more experience at than JS or jQuery).

Comment: For in is the same as a for each loop in C# or Java, which is what I know. I use .NET for my web development. But basically what it does is loop through any array or list and for each iteration it will store the value at the index into a temporary variable which you can use. For instance `for(var t in test)` loops through an array called test and stores a value in t, so the first iteration t will be the value at test[0], the second iteration t will be test[1] etc. Very useful when dealing with arrays

Comment: Its almost cleaner and simpler to me to use that syntax but what ever works for you

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson Your explanation about for in cannot be more incorrect, please read document first. For in => for (var index in array).
you HAVE to access value by index e.g : do test[t] in order to get value at index t.
For of : for(var v of array), however will store array value to v in each loop

https://jsfiddle.net/9f4cg2pp/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: That's for integer arrays, mine is a string array

Comment: Then explain to me why my fiddle works fine, I've always used it like that and be never have had problems as long as it's a simple array like that, on objects yes you would need to have do that because it's an object